# How to correct Python Attribute Error: Float object has no attribute 'set'

Tags: python

I get the `AttributeError: float object has no attribute set` at Line 61, in `calcmpg.self.mpg.set(self.mpg)`

How do I correct this?

Here is the program I've written:

This program prompts the user to enter number of miles driven and gallons consumed to calculate MPG.

```
import tkinter

import tkinter.messagebox

class MilesPerGallonGUI:

    def __init__(self):

                #create main window
        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()

                #create frames 
        self.frame1 = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.frame2 = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.frame3 = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.frame4 = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)

                #create label widgets
        self.label1 = tkinter.Label(self.frame1, text = 'Enter miles: ')
        self.label2 = tkinter.Label(self.frame2, text = 'Enter gallons: ')

                #create entry widgets
        self.entry1 = tkinter.Entry(self.frame1, width = 10)
        self.entry2 = tkinter.Entry(self.frame2, width = 10)

                #pack 
        self.label1.pack (side = 'left')
        self.entry1.pack (side = 'left')
        self.label2.pack (side = 'left')
        self.entry2.pack (side = 'left')

                #
        self.mpg = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.res = tkinter.Label(self.frame3, text = 'The MPG value is: ')
        self.res_label = tkinter.Label(self.frame3, textvariable = self.mpg)
        self.res.pack(side = 'left')
        self.res_label.pack(side = 'left')
        self.calc = tkinter.Button(self.frame4, text = 'Calculate MPG', command = self.calcmpg)
        self.quit_button = tkinter.Button(self.frame4, text = 'Quit', command = self.main_window.destroy)
        self.calc.pack(side = 'left')
        self.quit_button.pack(side = 'left')
        self.frame1.pack()
        self.frame2.pack()
        self.frame3.pack()
        self.frame4.pack()
        tkinter.mainloop()


                #calcmpg for a callback function for the calculate button
    def calcmpg(self):
        self.test1 = float(self.entry1.get())
        self.test2 = float(self.entry2.get())
        self.mpg = float(self.test1/self.test2)
        self.mpg.set(self.mpg)

gu = MilesPerGallonGUI()
```

Comment: You use `self.mpg = float(self.test1/self.test2)` so that creates a float, what should float.set do?

Comment: And why are you using `set` for , The error is raised because you are using set method on a floating point value.

Answer (score 4):

You set the variable to a float first:

```
self.mpg = float(self.test1/self.test2)
self.mpg.set(self.mpg)
```

so on that second line you are trying to use the *old* `StringVar` object, but that's no longer there.

Make `mpg` a local variable instead:

```
new_mpg = float(self.test1/self.test2)
self.mpg.set(new_mpg)
```

By not replacing `self.mpg` with a float, but using a new, separate local instead, you can still use the `StringVar` object methods.

Answer (score 4):

Replace the lines

```
self.mpg = float(self.test1/self.test2)
self.mpg.set(self.mpg)
```

by

```
self.mpg.set(float(self.test1/self.test2))
```

Comment: You all are awesome!!  I appreciate all your help!!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
    self.mpg = float(self.test1/self.test2)
    self.mpg.set(self.mpg)
```

Earlier, you have `self.mpg = tkinter.StringVar()`.  In the calcmpg method, however, you assign `self.mpg` to a float.  A float does not have a set method.